# Can I compare whether two floating-point number are equal in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following code is from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html?q=&p=0

This code calculates the fixpoint of cosine, which is a mathematical constant. It simply calls Math.cos repeatedly starting at 1.0 until the result doesn't change any more, yielding a result of 0.7390851332151607.

In my mind, we can't compare whether two floating-point number are equal, so I think that the result of `if (x == y)` is always false, right?

```
private fun findFixPoint(): Double {
    var x = 1.0
    while (true) {
        val y = Math.cos(x)
        if (x == y) return y
        x = y
    }
}
```

Comment: You can compare two floating points if you want, why couldn't you?. It's not a common scenario since it's a brittle solution for most problems. What you usually want to do is compare values within an epsilon of difference or use precise decimal arithmetics. In this case it looks like a valid solution since it's bound to converge to a certain value.

Comment: In some language, such as Fortran, floating-point number is not a accurate, so if (x==y) return y should be if (ABS(x-y)<0.0000000001) return y

Answer (score 4):

To further extend on my comment and getting more precise, the documentation gives you the key.

[Math.cos(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos(double))

> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results
>   must be semi-monotonic.

An ulp is the difference between an encoded floating point number and the next number that can be encoded in the data type, in this case, double.

If the result must be within 1 ulp, that means the result can be one of, at most,  two floating point values.

It follows that the only way that the computation wouldn't stop is if an input of one of these numbers will give you the other number. But since the function is semi-monotonic that means that can't happen. Otherwise you would have the higher value of the two as input giving you the lower value as output, and the lower value giving you the higher one as output. Semi-monotonic means it only goes in one direction (to put it very simply and somewhat inaccurately).

Answer (score 3):

> In my mind, we can't compare whether two floating-point number are equal, so I think that the result of if (x == y) is always false, right?

No, this is wrong. You **CAN** compare whether two floating-point number are equal but it is mostly meaningless. Because floating point by definition is not accurate. Even two different calculations have same result in Math, it does not necessary equal in program because of rounding error. It still may a chance to be equal.

Comment: Thanks! I assume that Math.cos(x) will be 0.7390851332151607 after I calculate 100 times manually, the code above will be calculate 500 times until x==yy, and when the  code above run again, maybe it need calculate 800 times until x==yy, right?

Comment: @HelloCW No, there are no guarantee they are equal even that are mathematical equal.

Comment: Thanks! If so, why did you think that the sample code is correct? I think it should be if (ABS(x-y)<0.0000000001) return y , the sample code will be infinite loop

Comment: @HelloCW I did not say it is correct. I just said it is possible that `x==y` even it is very small.

Comment: Do you mean that the x==y maybe true when x=1.0000000001 and y=1.0000000002

Comment: @HelloCW I mean float can equal but they have to be exact. `1.0000000001` and `1.0000000002` are not exact the same, so they are not equal. But there are rounding occurs in float which **MAY** make the final result equal.

Answer (score 2):

you can just write an extension function which compares both numbers using a given precision you decided is good enough to determine they are the same value.

```
fun Float.sameValueAs(other: Float) : Boolean {
   return (abs(this-other) < 0.0000000001)
}

//usage
val a = 0.0f
val b = 0.0f
a.equals(b)      //returs false
a.sameValueAs(b) //returns true
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post